# Rails routing: Scope using a database field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, multi-tenant, scoping

I am creating an multitenant app based on ideas from Ryan Bigg's book "Multitenancy with Rails". In this book, the tenants has their own subdomain. This approach is not applicable in my case, so I'm trying to scope by a slug of the account's name instead.

So instead of URLs like `http://account-name.myapp.com`, i want `http://myapp.mydomain.com/account-name/`. The subdomain is reserved for the app itself, because I want to be able to have more than one app on my domain.

Here's a piece of my routes.rb:

```
scope module: 'accounts' do
  resources :customers do
    resources :notes
  end
end
```

To achieve my goal, i try to follow the routing guide on [rubyonrails.com](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#prefixing-the-named-route-helpers) (the last code snippet in chapter 4.5), and change the above code to:

```
scope ':slug', module: 'accounts' do
  resources :customers do
    resources :notes
  end
end
```

`slug` is an attribute in the `accounts` table in the database, so if an account is called "My Business", the slug will typically be "my-business".

This change seems to correct my routes:

```
customers GET    /:slug/customers(.:format)
```

.. but it also seems to break my site, as the slug is not fetched from the database. I can't seem to wrap my mind around how this `scope':slug', module: 'accounts'` works. Is Rails supposed to automatically recognize :slug as an attribute of the Accoounts table? If not, can anyone please help me find a way to use the account's slug in my URLs?

I have googled around for a couple of days now, and read numerous answers here on Stackoverflow. Nothing helped, so any pointers is greatly appreciated. :-)

EDIT:

The relevant controllers are set up like this:

```
controllers/accounts/base_controller.rb
controllers/accounts/customers_controller.rb
controllers/accounts/products_controlelr.rb
controllers/accounts_controller.rb
controllers/application_controller.rb
```

The accounts_controller.rb only has actions for new and create at this point.

The accounts/base_controller.rb look like this:

```
module Accounts
 class BaseController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authorize_user!

  def current_account
   @current_account ||= Account.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
  end
  ...
 end
end
```

I addded this to my Account model:

```
def to_param
  slug
end
```

Before i tried to implement `scope ':slug'` in my routes, everyting worked when logged in users where directed to myapp.mydomain.com/dashboard and navigated to i.e. myapp.mydomain.com/customers. Now it works with myapp.mydomain.com/account-name/dashboard, but as soon as I try to navigate to a view that use helpers like `new_customer_path`, i get the error:

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"accounts/customers", :id=>nil, :slug=>#

I hope this makes my issue clearer. :-)

Comment: so you want a url looks like `http://myapp.mydomain.com/account-name/customers`?

Comment: Yes, "customers" is one example of my controllers in the accounts module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether your routes is set up correctly or not because you didn't post your controller source code, but basically how it works if very simple. If you are using the current routes you set up what you should do is create an `account_customers_controller.rb` file in `controllers\account\`folder, and it should look like this:

```
class Accounts::CustomersController < ActionController::Base
  def show
    @account = Account.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: hi if you found it helpful please accept my solution, or if you have problem i can help more

Comment: That was it!! I also had to update my `link_to`'s so they used the helpers with `params[:slug]`, but your answer helped me fix my accounts/base_controller.rb as shown in the updated part of my question. Thanks for your help! :-)